# how to keep some objects and remove other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove some object with `num` class.

html:

```
<a class='num'>1</a>
<a class='num'>2</a>
<a class='num'>3</a>
<a class='num numa'>4</a>
<a class='num'>5</a>
<a class='num'>6</a>
<a class='num'>7</a>
<a class='num'>8</a>
<a class='num'>9</a>
<a class='num'>10</a>
```

but I also want to keep objects around `numa`.

I want to keep three objects before and three objects after `numa` plus `numa`.

this is my try:

```
<script>
    var ind = $('.num:contains("4")').index();
    for(i=0; i<$('.num').size(); i++)
    {
        if(i<ind-3 || i>ind+3) $('.page_num:eq('+ind+')').remove();
    }
</script>
```

any idea?

Comment: have you tried out my solution.?

Comment: yes, but this type of selector `a[class='num numa']` is not usefull here. because I may add more class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice` method and exclude the elements using `not` method. As `index` method has been used this also selects and removes the elements if they are not siblings in the page.

```
var $e = $('a.num'),
    $t = $e.filter('.numa'),
    i  = $e.index($t), 
    $k = $e.slice(i-3, i+4);

$e.not($k).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WnDS2/

Edit: 
As your fiddle demonstrates, if the first parameter that is passed to the `slice` method is a negative number, `slice` method doesn't filter the elements, you can check the length of the selected elements and if the result of subtraction is a negative number set it to 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/WnDS2/5/

Comment: @Pooya Bale, because in your fiddle the first parameter that is passed to the `slice` method is negative, http://jsfiddle.net/WnDS2/5/

Answer (score 1):

First use the attribute selector to get the index of the particular anchor tag, and then use the [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to iterate through the all a elements and remove the required things using the following logic, Try this,

```
 var xIndex=$("a[class='num numa']").index()

      $("a").each(function(i)
                  {
             if(xIndex - 3 > i || xIndex + 3 < i)
                {
                  $(this).remove();
                }
                  })
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LpqAS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This: 
var index = $(".numa").index();
$(".numa").siblings().slice(index,index + 3).remove();
$(".numa").siblings().slice(index - 3, index).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) selector:

```
var ind = $('.numa').index();
$('.num:nth-child(-n+'+(ind-3 >= 0 ? ind-3 : 0)+'), .num:nth-child(n+'+(ind+5)+')').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AgbAU/1/

*the part `ind-3 >= 0 ? ind-3 : 0` prevents situation like `nth-child(-n+-1)` which is incorrect syntax.*

filter method can also be usefull:

```
var ind = $('.numa').index();
$('.num').filter(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    return i < ind - 3 || i > ind + 3;
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AgbAU/2/